# Unable to receive file in spring mvc ( servlet 3.1) sent from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, file-upload

I'am trying to initiate the uploading of the file from **AngularJS** and send that file to the server,(Spring-mvc) and further process and manipulate the file received.. 
    And in the controller side after a long research done i figured out in [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) to receive the file in spring in 2 ways, and i tried both the methodologies, but i am having issues in receiving the file passed from angularjs..

This is how i am sending selecting and sending the file from angular.

**JSP page**

```
     <input type="text" name="description" ng-model="description"/>
     <input type="file"  name="file" file-input="files"  style="background-color:#F0F0F0 ;  ;color:black;" />

     <button name ="uploadFile" ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
```

**fileInput Directive**

```
    fmApp.directive("fileInput",function(){
return {
    scope:{
        fileInput: "="
    },
    link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
        console.log("-----Inside file Input Directive---------");
        ele.bind("change",function(changeEvent){
            var reader=new FileReader();
            reader.onload=function(loadEvent){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.fileInput=loadEvent.target.result;
                    console.log("fileInput==::  "+scope.fileInput);
                });
            }
            reader.readAsText(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            console.log("reader    : "+reader );
            /*scope.$apply(function(){
                scope.fileInput=reader;
            })*/
        });
    }
}
```

});

**Angular Controller**

```
   $scope.uploadFile=function(){
        console.log("--------Inside uploadFile()--------");
        var file=$scope.files;
        console.log("Selected file is : "+JSON.stringify(file));
        var uploadUrl="fileManipulation.html";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file,uploadUrl,$scope.description);
    };
```

**fileUpload Service**

```
    fmApp.service("fileUpload",function($resource,$http){
        console.log("--------Inside fileUpload service---------");
        this.uploadFileToUrl=function(file,uploadUrl,description){
        console.log("--------Inside uploadFile function---------");
        var fd =new FormData();
        fd.append('file',file);
        fd.append('description',description);
        $http.post(uploadUrl,fd,{
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
     })
    .success(function(){
        alert("success");
    })
    .error(function(){
        alert("Error");
    })
   }
});
```

And then in the controller side i am using **servlet 3.1**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/fileManipulation" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFileQM( HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("---Inside File Manipulation Request Mapping-----");

        // Servlet 3.1's implementation.....
        String description = request.getParameter("description"); // Retrieves <input type="text" name="description">
        System.out.println("-----File Description-----"+description);

        Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); // Retrieves <input type="file" name="file">
        System.out.println("-----File Received-----------");

        String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
        System.out.println("-----FileName------:"+fileName);

        long fileSize=filePart.getSize();
        System.out.println("-----File Size-------"+fileSize);

       InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();

       //Extracting the contents in InputStream into String..
       BufferedReader br=null;
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try{
            br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileContent));
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(br!=null){
                try{
                    br.close();
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        line=sb.toString();
        System.out.println("----The contents of the file are ----\n"+line);
                return null;

    }
```

Ones i select the file from the angularjs and put in the **form-data** and send that request to the spring mvc  and try to display the basic file info such as **file name and size** , the value  i get is **undefined**, it seems that the actual contents have not been received in the spring..

But the same controller works  fine and the file info is acquired, when the file selection and submitting process is done as part of the jsp with in the  tag, like in the below code  snippet.

And the problem with this is that, the response is returned as a completely new **view** redirecting to a different blank page..

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/Customerinfo/fileManipulation.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"">
                <input type="text" name="description"/>
                <input type="file" name="file"/>
                <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

I want the request to be received as part of it made from **angularJS** and not from normal **jsp** format, so that i can handle the response back in angular in my own way..

Please help me out to resolve this problem which has held me up from many days, with your suggestions..        cheers..

Comment: You don't have file access in browser using javascript for security reasons. Can do it with flash but not all browsers will run flash

Comment: There are lots of tutorials for uploading files to server as well as angular and javascript upload plugins

Comment: @charlietfl please reconsider my question  which i have updated and kindly suggest me your view on it..